# Use jQuery UI Spinner Control with an Absolute positioned element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I dynamically create some controls on a screen, and I would like to use the jQuery UI spinner control for numeric fields.  I am positioning my elements using absolute, but it does not seem to work with the UI control.  I have created a jsfiddle with an example of two controls.  The absolute control will not work.

https://jsfiddle.net/41u0kjsb/

```
<input type="text" style="height:18px;width:40px;top:55px;left:255px;position:absolute;z-index:101;font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;text-align:right;padding-right:2px;" pt_properties="biu" pt_format="" pt_mask="" pt_readonly="False" pt_required="False" pt_dmn="QTY_FURN_100M" pt_type="N_NUMERIC" title="qty_furn_100M (QTY_FURN_100M)" tabindex="1" id="control1" maxlength="255" value="1">
<br><br><br>
<input type="text" style="height:18px;width:40px;position:relative;z-index:101;font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;text-align:left;padding-right:2px;" pt_properties="biu" pt_format="" pt_mask="" pt_readonly="False" pt_required="False" pt_dmn="QTY_FURN_100M" pt_type="N_NUMERIC" title="qty_furn_100M (QTY_FURN_100M)" tabindex="1" id="control2" maxlength="255" value="1">

  $('input[PT_TYPE="N_NUMERIC"]').spinner();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set the position on the widget. Instead, set it on the spinner's wrapper after it has been created:

```
<input id="spin" style="position:relative;">
```

and then:

```
$('#spin').spinner();
$('#spin').parent(".ui-spinner").css({
    position: "absolute"
});
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/3rf0xhqr/